# return nearest adjacent rows that are earlier/later by date to another table's date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Problem: to return a single result set based on the following

for each date in report table (rdate) return the latest transaction table (tdate) that is earlier or equal to rdate (plus t1 & t2)  as sdate,s1,s2

for each date in report table (rdate) return the earliest transaction table (tdate) that is later or equal to rdate (plus t1 & t2) as edate,e1,e2

Have attempted TOP 1 / APPLY / LEAD& LAG code, but cannot get results as required.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

**Report table**

| rdate |
| --- |
| 06/01/2021 |
| 26/01/2021 |
| 15/02/2021 |

**Transaction table**

| tdate | t1 | t2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 17 | 6 |
| 05/01/2021 | 5 | 9 |
| 09/01/2021 | 8 | 12 |
| 19/01/2021 | 15 | 11 |
| 20/01/2021 | 12 | 8 |
| 25/01/2021 | 9 | 1 |
| 26/01/2021 | 8 | 17 |
| 30/01/2021 | 7 | 6 |
| 08/02/2021 | 6 | 21 |
| 22/02/2021 | 14 | 5 |
| 27/02/2021 | 11 | 4 |

**Result required**

| rdate | sdate | s1 | s2 | edate | e1 | e2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/01/2021 | 05/01/2021 | 5 | 9 | 09/01/2021 | 8 | 12 |
| 26/01/2021 | 26/01/2021 | 8 | 17 | 26/01/2021 | 8 | 17 |
| 15/02/2021 | 08/02/2021 | 6 | 21 | 22/02/2021 | 14 | 5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` together with a `SELECT TOP 1` with appropriate order and filter criteria should do the trick.  Try:

```
DECLARE @ReportTable TABLE (rdate DATETIME)
INSERT @ReportTable
VALUES
    ('2021-01-06'),
    ('2021-01-26'),
    ('2021-02-15')

DECLARE @TransactionTable TABLE (tdate DATETIME, t1 INT, t2 INT)
INSERT @TransactionTable
VALUES
    ('2021-01-01', 17, 6),
    ('2021-01-05', 5, 9),
    ('2021-01-09', 8, 12),
    ('2021-01-19', 15, 11),
    ('2021-01-20', 12, 8),
    ('2021-01-25', 9, 1),
    ('2021-01-26', 8, 17),
    ('2021-01-30', 7, 6),
    ('2021-02-08', 6, 21),
    ('2021-02-22', 14, 5),
    ('2021-02-27', 11, 4)

SELECT * -- TODO: Assign meaningful names here
FROM @ReportTable R
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @TransactionTable T1
    WHERE T1.tdate <= R.rdate
    ORDER BY T1.tdate DESC
) S
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @TransactionTable T2
    WHERE T2.tdate >= R.rdate
    ORDER BY T2.tdate
) E
ORDER BY R.rdate
```

The `OUTER APPLY` is like the `LEFT JOIN` equivalent of `CROSS APPLY`, allowing for no record found.  Take a close look at the inequality conditions to ensure that the edge cases are as intended.

Comment: Thanks ...small edit to make ....
WHERE T2.tdate >= R.rdate

Comment: Done, Which now matches up with the posted "result required". It is unusual to see both ends of a date range to be a closed. Typically I see DateRangeStart <= EventDate < DateRangeEnd, where DateRangeEnd is also the start date of the next date range.

Comment: needed to ensure that if tdate = rdate, then the return is only t1/t2 for that date